# api inicio de sesion Google Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

Buena Tardes, estoy intentando usar la API para el inicio de sesión desde los service-google pero me arroja los siguiente errores:

**Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpatch()'
Possible causes:The project 'MapasAndroid' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project**

Este error ya lo solucione con esto:

[image: error]

- The project 'MapasAndroid' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
  "open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file
  **No se como se resolveria ese problema sin embargo aqui esta lo que tengo en el gradle wrapper.properties[image: gradle wrapper.properties]**
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
  Apply Gradle plugin
  **probe todos los "plugin" y nada lo soluciono :(**

Gradle APP[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a quien me pueda dar una solucion

Comment: En tus dependencias no es **classpatch**, es **classpath**, corrige eso. Saludos.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el Gradle(Modulo app)

Comment: Amigo gracias estabas en lo correcto me funciono :) la imagen de Gradle la dejo en post de la pregunta